# CTE - Incorrect Syntax near '.'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my code:

```
  With table_CTE(a.PolicyNumber, Amount, 
b.PolicyNumber, FundValue)
 as
(
Select a.PolicyNumber, Amount,
b.PolicyNumber, FundValue
    from ( Select PolicyNumber, Amount, 
    from table.a
       ) as a
    
    Full Outer Join
        (Select PolicyNumber, FundValue
        from table.b
       ) as b
        on
    a.PolicyNumber = b.PolicyNumber
)
```

I am trying to create a CTE statement but keep getting the error :
"Incorrect syntax near '.'

Comment: Also, after the `WITH .... AS ( ....)` there must be a SQL statement that uses/references that CTE....

Answer (score 1):

Column names don't support periods.  Perhaps you intend:

```
With table_CTE (PolicyNumber, InvestmentCode, IndexType, Amount, FundID, 
PolicyNumber, FundValue, DepositDate, FundID, [Difference])
```

That said, you don't have to repeat the column aliases in the CTE definition.  They are all assigned in the `select`, you can can use use:

```
with table_CTE as (
    select . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
    With table_CTE as (Select INDCONEX.PolicyNumber, INDCONEX.InvestmentCode, 
     IndexType, Amount, INDCONEX.FundID, 
     INTCRDEX.PolicyNumber, FundValue, DepositDate, INTCRDEX.FundID, [Difference])

      (
      Select INDCONEX.PolicyNumber, INDCONEX.InvestmentCode,IndexType, Amount, 
      INDCONEX.FundID, 
       INTCRDEX.PolicyNumber, FundValue, DepositDate, INTCRDEX.FundID,
        abs (INDCONEX.Amount-INTCRDEX.FundValue) as [Difference]
    from ( Select PolicyNumber, InvestmentCode, IndexType,Amount, FundID 
   from FinancialExtracts.dbo.INDCONEX
        where RunDate = '20200531' and InvestmentCode >3) as INDCONEX

Full Outer Join
    (Select PolicyNumber, FundValue, DepositDate, FundID
    from FinancialExtracts.dbo.INTCRDEX
        where RunDate = '20200531' and InvestmentCode > 3) as INTCRDEX 
    on
INDCONEX.PolicyNumber = INTCRDEX.PolicyNumber and
INDCONEX.FundID = INTCRDEX.FundID
```

Comment: I am just learning SQL so thank you for your answer. When I run this code I get errors saying "The multi-part identifier "INDCONEX.PolicyNumber" could not be bound" for most of the objects. Do you know what this error means?

Comment: Yes ! You have written policy number twice just write it once and donot use column aliases in the CTE definition

Comment: The query above is pulling columns from two different tables (INDCONEX and INTCRDEX) and combining them based on PolicyNumber (because both tables have the same policy numbers). When I only list PolicyNumber once I get an error saying "table_CTE has more columns than specified in the column list" How do I go about listing the columns that are listed in both tables (PolicyNumber, FundID)?

Comment: In select statement also you are writing once ?
          Select INDCONEX.PolicyNumber, INDCONEX.InvestmentCode,IndexType, 
         Amount, 
         INDCONEX.FundID, 
       INTCRDEX.PolicyNumber, FundValue, DepositDate, INTCRDEX.FundID,
        abs (INDCONEX.Amount-INTCRDEX.FundValue) as [Difference]

Answer (score 0):

You should not qualify the column names in the cte's header with aliases of the table names used inside the cte.
Also `table.a` and `table.b` are not valid table names (because they contain the `.`).
If these are the actual names then you should enclose them in square brackets: `[table.a]` and `[table.b]`.
But I believe that you just want to use aliases for them and this is not the correct way to do it.
You are over-complicating the cte.
It is as simple as this:

```
with table_CTE as (
  select a.PolicyNumber PolicyNumbera, a.Amount,
         b.PolicyNumber PolicyNumberb, b.FundValue
  from tablea as a full outer join tableb as b
  on a.PolicyNumber = b.PolicyNumber
)
```

Replace `tablea` and `tableb` with the actual table names.
The columns `a.PolicyNumber` and `b.PolicyNumber` return column with the same name and this is not allowed, this is why I aliased them to `PolicyNumbera` and `PolicyNumberb`.